# Convert complex XML file to data frame in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, datatable, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert an XML file to a data frame in R. Here is a sample of the xml file :

```
<Games timestamp="2016-12-02T09:06:51">
<Game id="853139" away_team_id="143" away_team_name="Lyon" competition_id="24" competition_name="French Ligue 1" game_date="2016-08-14T14:00:00" home_team_id="148" home_team_name="Nancy" matchday="1" period_1_start="2016-08-14T14:00:25" period_2_start="2016-08-14T15:02:29" season_id="2016" season_name="Season 2016/2017">
<Event id="1195160021" event_id="1" type_id="34" period_id="16" min="0" sec="0" team_id="143" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2016-08-14T13:08:34.349" last_modified="2016-08-14T13:59:59" version="1471179598746">
  <Q id="1117749718" qualifier_id="194" value="59963" />
  <Q id="1807420796" qualifier_id="30" value="59957, 54772, 37832, 59963, 44488, 52775, 169007, 168568, 59966, 166552, 149519, 220560, 173211, 55305, 107641, 37852, 59956, 71389" />
  <Q id="450557206" qualifier_id="197" value="645" />
  <Q id="1671039854" qualifier_id="131" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" />
  <Q id="108315093" qualifier_id="227" value="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" />
  <Q id="582175015" qualifier_id="44" value="1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" />
  <Q id="1069121575" qualifier_id="130" value="4" />
  <Q id="459298302" qualifier_id="59" value="1, 20, 15, 21, 2, 3, 14, 8, 10, 18, 27, 22, 4, 7, 12, 28, 30, 31" />
</Event>
<Event id="2066606636" event_id="1" type_id="34" period_id="16" min="0" sec="0" team_id="148" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2016-08-14T13:08:35.580" last_modified="2016-08-14T15:03:52" version="1471183432594">
  <Q id="891471807" qualifier_id="194" value="171101" />
  <Q id="201984211" qualifier_id="30" value="38816, 80799, 43024, 9980, 170034, 171101, 210460, 214472, 51327, 38008, 97290, 63600, 152337, 209874, 44314, 214473, 93498, 54911" />
  <Q id="478809608" qualifier_id="131" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" />
  <Q id="974533808" qualifier_id="227" value="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" />
  <Q id="193300652" qualifier_id="44" value="1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" />
  <Q id="1493018979" qualifier_id="130" value="4" />
  <Q id="454462015" qualifier_id="59" value="16, 14, 26, 25, 4, 2, 13, 6, 9, 7, 23, 1, 3, 8, 12, 17, 19, 28" />
</Event>
<Event id="931188097" event_id="2" type_id="32" period_id="1" min="0" sec="0" team_id="143" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2016-08-14T14:00:25.556" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:00:26" version="1471179625559">
  <Q id="674324086" qualifier_id="127" value="Right to Left" />
</Event>
<Event id="704339764" event_id="2" type_id="32" period_id="1" min="0" sec="0" team_id="148" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2016-08-14T14:00:25.556" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:00:27" version="1471179626429">
  <Q id="2090199938" qualifier_id="127" value="Left to Right" />
</Event>
</Game>
</Games>
```

I have tried to use "XML" and "xml2" packages but nothing very conclusive as I am not familiar at all with xml  files.

```
x = read_xml("f24-24-2016-853139-eventdetails.xml")

x_list = as_list(x)

x_df <- x_list %>% map('Game') %>% flatten() %>% map_df(flatten)
```

Does someone could explain how to deal with that kind of files and how to convert it to a data frame in R ?
Thanks

Comment: I really, really, really don't want to retype your sampledata.. please make your problem reproducible.. Also, please dont ask for code without showing any effords made by yourself. There are plenty totorials in how to process xml using the xml2-package (which I would use). Please give it a couple of go's yourself, and come back with more specific questions. SO is not a coding factory. Plenty of coders out there which you can hire if you do not want/can do the job yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post and added a sample of the xml file and the code I tried but gave me an empty dataframe

Comment: And what is your desired output? Please show what parts are intended to be extracted.

Comment: PabloBalian, as @Parfait says: what should your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, here is an idea on how you can extract data from your xml to build a data.frame.

The 'trick' is to start with the 'lowest' node you need, and use `xpath`-operators to get relevant parent/ancestor/sibling nodes... In your xml, the 'lowest' node is the Q-node, so get these, and work from there

```
#load libraries
library(xml2)
library(magrittr) #for the pipe-operator

#load xml
doc = read_xml("f24-24-2016-853139-eventdetails.xml")

#get all Q-nodes
 q.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//Q" )

#build data frame
 result <- data.frame( Game.id = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_find_first( ".//ancestor::Game" ) %>% 
                         xml_attr( "id" ) %>% 
                         as.numeric(),
                       Game.away_team_name = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_find_first( ".//ancestor::Game" ) %>% 
                         xml_attr( "away_team_name" ),
                       Game.home_team_name = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_find_first( ".//ancestor::Game" ) %>% 
                         xml_attr( "home_team_name" ),
                       Event.id = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_find_first( ".//parent::Event" ) %>% 
                         xml_attr( "id" ) %>% 
                         as.numeric(),
                       Q.id = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_attr( "id" ),
                       Q.qualifier_id = q.nodes %>% 
                         xml_attr( "qualifier_id" ) %>% 
                         as.numeric(), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

**result**

```
head( result )
#   Game.id Game.away_team_name Game.home_team_name   Event.id       Q.id Q.qualifier_id
# 1  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021 1117749718            194
# 2  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021 1807420796             30
# 3  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021  450557206            197
# 4  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021 1671039854            131
# 5  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021  108315093            227
# 6  853139                Lyon               Nancy 1195160021  582175015             44
```